# Why can't I call .Add() on my list of float?

Tags: c#, .net

So I have an inner class:

```
public class RegressEquation 
{
    public List<float> coefficients = new List<float>();
    float averageDiff = 0;

    public  RegressEquation(float[] coefficients, float finalAverageDiff)
    {
        averageDiff = finalAverageDiff;

        foreach (float f in coefficients)
        {
            coefficients.Add(f);
        }
    }
}
```

But I am getting a compiler error when I call coefficients.Add(f);  that says "System.Array does not contain a definition for Add..."  The documentation says that Add() is a method in List<>.  How can I get rid of this error?

Comment: You have a local `float[] coefficients` as a parameter for that method which takes precedence.

Comment: `List<float> coefficients` and `float[] coefficients` have the same name, consider calling `this.coefficients.Add(f);`, it might work.

Comment: This is why we follow common conventions for naming things. Public class level variables generally start with a capital letter (Pascal case)

Comment: This is why the C# style guidelines state that public fields are Pascal cased...  Follow the style guidelines and you would have avoided this problem.  Also, why use a public field at all?  Shouldnt this be a public _property)_ with a _private_ set?

Comment: As an aside, the explicit `foreach` loop isn't necessary; either `this.coefficients = new List<float>(coefficients)` or `this.coefficients = coefficients.ToList()` would work. Either of these would actually be more efficient than adding elements in a loop, since it allows the list to pre-size itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you have a method argument with that same name, and name resolution prescribes that local variables rule over class-level variables.

Change the name of either of the variables, or use `this` to make specific you want to address the class-level variable:

```
foreach (float f in coefficients)
{
    this.coefficients.Add(f);
}
```

Comment: Or explicitly disambiguate with `this.coefficients`. It's not exactly unusual for constructor arguments to have the same name as fields they initialize.

Comment: Not the d-voter but I think it takes more than changing the name doesn't it?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils No, it didn't.

Comment: OK, you can't rename "either one of them". You have to rename the array so that you're calling `Add` on a list. But you edited that away...

Comment: Renaming either of the variables and their references will remove the ambiguity. @ChiefTwoPencils

Comment: Yes, sorry too early I guess.

Comment: Renaming will avoid the ambiguity and will fix OPs problem, but the important thing to avoid it the next time, is mentioned in the first paragraph.

Comment: oh duh well I feel stupid,  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

A little naming convention can clear this up for you. I use rules with my class level variables to distinguish them from local variables and arguments without having to use `this`. Consider the following:

```
public class RegressEquation
{
    public List<float> Coefficients; // start this with a capital
    // … more code here.

    public  RegressEquation(float[] coefficients, float finalAverageDiff)
    {
        AverageDiff = finalAverageDiff;
        Coefficients = new List<float>(coefficients);
    }
}
```